# How to make Facebook display all the OG images that are set up on page? I see only 4

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I've made debug on facebook debugger and all looks ok, no errors but.. I see only 5 images on preview when trying to post on facebook, it let's me choose of 5, while there is a gallery and I'd like to choose from 20 images.
Any posibility? Found nothing on this topic.

Thanks for your time & Hope for answer

Comment: we cannot help you without the code and (even more important) a link to test

Comment: i can chooose 5 of them. not sure if it´s really intended to choose from that many, to be honest.